ManagedIdentity based SQL role created while creating a SQL Azure Database using HELM Chart
Is there a way to specify a workloadIdentity which should be granted as specific SQL role (for example db_owner) in the created Azure SQL Database?. This would allow me to create a database using helm chart and assign the managed identity which is granted to use it without specifying user name/password and later on executing a custom script which assigns the role.
I tried to use the Azure Service Operator which provides some parameters in the sql.azure.com/v1 CRD's however it does not seem it works with an AD account.

Azure SQL Database supports Azure AD authentication, which allows you to use identities managed by Azure AD to authenticate to your database. You can use Azure AD authentication with managed identities to authenticate to your database without specifying a username or password.
